# TV mount to 5" door frame instead of stud?

Tags: wood, framing, mounting

I have a 1906 Edwardian with solid 5" x 5" door frames. I just noticed that (because of stud positions) using the door frame instead of a stud would allow me to install the TV in a better position. Looking inside the wall, the door frames seem to be made of the same material as the studs.

The frame doesn't go to the ceiling but it's huge compared to the studs. Would you use it as a stud for TV mounting purposes?

Thank you!

Comment: I'd be reluctant to put holes in that old wood, and I'm not sure I'd ever want a TV so close to a door. That said, this is really a matter of opinion, and therefore off topic. Obviously the wood will hold up.

Comment: How about a picture of the door frame and the TV bracket.

Comment: I have never seen a doorframe that is not connected to the Sealing somehow. I have the feeling you got that wrong. What holds the door when it is open or somebody pushes down on the door?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are fine. Predrill the holes because its dry wood. The frame is for sure connected to the studs even if the frame does not connect to the ceiling.